# getting a password prompt when running ansibleplaybook

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I have written an ansible playbook to install vnc. I want to ensure when someone runs the playbook they are prompted for a password. I was able to run the playbook via some code i put together and it prompts for the password but accepts any password.

```
---
- hosts : test-server
  vars_prompt:

- name: password
  prompt: "What is your password?"
  private: yes

  tasks :
   - name : install tightvncserver
     package : pkg=tightvncserver state=installed

  notify:
   - start tightvncserver

  handlers :
   - name : start tightvncserver
     service : name=tightvncserver state=started
```

Please excuse the indentation. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the **rest** of your question: "but accepts any password ... " and what? it needs to be stronger? it needs to be of a certain length? you want to skip it sometimes?

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation of your question, as the `- name: password` block should be indented under the `vars_prompt:`

Comment: I want to set the password myself and make it mandatory when running the playbook

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is where ansible vault comes into picture. Any password or other confidential information has to be stored in ansible vault. If you are not worried about security then you can simply add a `when` module to check if password matches a specific string or else the best way to solve this would be to prompt for ansible vault password and fetch confidential informations from there.
Alternatively, you can also store your password as key value in a yml variable file and `include` that in your playbook and add a `when` condition to check if password provided equals the password mentioned in that variable file.